# For which probability distributions does $\lim_{n\to\infty} \mathbb{E}\left[\left(\sum_1^n X_i\right)^2 / \left(\sum_1^n {X_i}^2\right)\right]$ exist?

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, random-variables

Say, we have $n$ positive i.i.d. random variables, $X_1, X_2, \dots, X_n$ which are distributed according to some probability distribution, $f$. So, only distributions on either $[0, 1]$ or $[0, +\infty]$.

The expected value of the ratio between the square of the sum and the sum of squares is then a function of $n$ and the distribution $f$,

$$ G(n; f) = \mathbb{E}\left[\frac{\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n} X_i\right)^2}{\sum_{i=1}^{n} X_i^2 } \right] $$

In general, I am interested in the behavior of this function, especially in the large-$n$ limit, or as $n \to \infty$. **Specifically, for which distributions is $G(n; f)$ asymptotically constant?**

It's easy to see that $G(n)$ is invariant to scaling such as $X_i \to a X_i$. So, there is no loss of generality when limiting ourselves to either distributions on $[0, 1]$ or $[0, +\infty]$. However, I suspect that it is not possible to get constant $G$ at large-$n$ for distributions on bounded intervals, anyway.

---

Here's how far I've gotten myself:

Firstly, we know that $1 \le G(n) \le n$ by the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality. $G(n) = n$ is only true for the Dirac delta distribution ($X_i = 1$).

It seems for some common distributions I tried out numerically, $G(n; f) \propto n$ in the large-$n$ limit. For example, with the uniform distribution, as $n \to \infty$

$$ G(n; U(0, 1)) \sim \frac{3}{4} n$$

I used some very non-rigorous manipulation ("physicist math"), assuming that the expected value of the ratio is the ratio of expected values in the large-$n$ limit, to derive

$$ G(n; f) \sim \frac{\mu^2}{\mu^2 + \sigma^2} n$$

where $f$ is a distribution with mean $\mu$ and variance $\sigma^2$. Numerically, this seems to agree with the uniform and log-normal distributions. My guess is that it applies to any distribution with finite mean and variance.

---

Numerically, I also found that for power-law distributions with heavy tails (such as [Pareto distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pareto_distribution) with $\alpha < 1$), $G(n)$ does appear to converge to a constant. But I can't seem to show this mathematically or find an expression for $G(n)$ in terms of $\alpha$.

Edit: An interesting, perhaps useful result from [Albrecher & Teugels (2007)](https://www.ams.org/journals/tpms/2007-74-00/S0094-9000-07-00692-8/), is that if $f$ is a Pareto-type distribution with $0 < \alpha < 1$, then

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \mathbb{E}\left[\frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n} X_i^2 }{\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n} X_i\right)^2}\right] = {1 - \alpha} $$

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/148204/discussion-on-question-by-xyzt-for-which-probability-distributions-does-lim-n); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score 3):

If the strong law of large numbers applies, then
$$ \left(\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n X_i\right)^2 \xrightarrow{\text{a.s.}} E[X]^2, \qquad \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n {X_i}^2 \xrightarrow{\text{a.s.}} E[X^2].$$

Thus,
$$
\frac{1}{n}\frac{\left(\sum X_i\right)^2}{\left(\sum {X_i}^2 \right)} = 
  \frac{\left(\frac{1}{n}\sum X_i\right)^2}{\left(\frac{1}{n}\sum {X_i}^2 \right)} \xrightarrow{\text{a.s.}} \frac{E[X]^2}{E[X^2]}.
$$

Therefore, if the strong law of large numbers applies for $\{X_i\}$ and $\{X_i^2\}$, then $$ \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{G(n)}{n} = \frac{E[X]^2}{E[X^2]}.$$

From which we have that if $E[X]>0$, then $G(n) \to \infty$ as $n\to\infty$.

Comment: As @Henry pointed out, OP is most likely wondering about for what $f$ is $\frac{1}{n}G(n)$ converging to a constant. And you showed that for at least all $f$ for which the SLLN applies, namely, at least all $f$ that have finite first moment.

Comment: @WilliamM. Apparently I was wrong about that.  In any case you need a finite moment to say $\left(\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n X_i\right)^2 \xrightarrow{\text{a.s.}} E[X]^2$ while the question does not suggest this

Comment: @WilliamM. It's amazing how you are the second person now to simply refuse to acknowledge that I meant to ask the question I asked.

Comment: @XYZT if you only consider densities on $[0, 1],$ then this answers shows that "For no distribution (in this class) will $G(n)$ converge, and for all distributions (in this class) will $G(n) \sim c n,$ for a $c$ depending on the distribution." If this is not enough to what you are asking, then you probably don't know what you want to ask. If you allow for densities on $[0, \infty),$ then the problem is much harder.

Comment: If you bothered to read the question I posted, you would see that I did indeed say as much. "However, I suspect that it is not possible to get constant G
 at large-n for distributions on bounded intervals, anyway." Not only that, I literally provide a valid expression for the behavior of G(n) for distributions with finite moments.

Comment: @XYZT, I have added an example when the LLT does not apply.

Comment: Also @XYZT, in my previous answer, I have provided sufficient conditions for which $G(n)$ diverges. I think that provides value to the post. I never said I had answered your question in totality, only for the cases in which LLT applies. Furthermore, that helped me to think about the example I provided.

Comment: Well, in the end, the example was not correct. I deleted it.

Answer (score 3):

In this answer, we

1. prove that $\frac{G(n, f)}{n} \to \frac{\mathbf{E}[X]^2}{\mathbf{E}[X^2]} $ whenever $\mathbf{E}[X] < \infty$, and
2. show that $G(n, f)$ converges to some constant for some distribution $f$.

The statement and proof of each of the above claims will be demonstrated below, but let me make some informal remarks first.

The asymptotic behavior of $G(n, f)$ is determined by the survival function $R(t) = \mathbf{P}(X > t)$, which measures how much the distribution of $X$ is heavy-tailed. Indeed, $G(n, f)$ grows more slowly when $f$ is more heavy-tailed (or $R(t)$ decays more slowly). A heuristic computation shows:

1. If $R(t)$ decays fast enough so that $\mathbf{E}[X^2] < \infty$, then $G(n,f) \asymp n$.
2. If $R(t) \asymp t^{-2}$, then $G(n, f) \asymp (\log n)^2$.
3. If $R(t) \asymp t^{-(1+\alpha)} $ for some $0 < \alpha < 1$, then $G(n, f)$ converges.

In my answer, both Claim 1 and a special case of Claim 3 is proved. If you are interested, I will try to hack the other cases and/or generalize the claims.

---

**Part 1.** Assume $\mathbf{P}(X > 0) = 1$ and $\mathbf{E}[X] < \infty$. Then

$$ \frac{G(n, f)}{n} = \mathbf{E}\Biggl[ \frac{\left( \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^{n} X_i \right)^2}{\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n} X_i^2} \Biggr]. $$

Either by Cauchy–Schwarz inequality or Jensen's inequality, we find that

$$ 0 \leq \frac{\left( \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^{n} X_i \right)^2}{\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n} X_i^2} \leq 1. $$

Moreover, by the strong law of large numbers,<sup>1)</sup>

$$ \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^{n} X_i \to \mathbf{E}[X] \in (0, \infty)
\qquad\text{and}\qquad
\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^{n} X_i^2 \to \mathbf{E}[X^2] \in (0, \infty] $$

almost surely as $n\to\infty$. So by the dominated convergence theorem,

$$ \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{G(n, f)}{n}
= \mathbf{E}\Biggl[ \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{\left( \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^{n} X_i \right)^2}{\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n} X_i^2} \Biggr]
= \frac{\mathbf{E}[X]^2}{\mathbf{E}[X^2]}. $$

---

**Part 2.** The main claim of this part is as follow:

> **Theorem.** In the case $f$ is the Pareto distribution,
>
> $$ f_{X_i}(x) = f(x) = \frac{\alpha}{x^{\alpha+1}} \mathbf{1}_{\{x > 1\}}, $$
>
> where $0 < \alpha < 1$, the quantity $G(n, f)$ converges:
>
> $$ \bbox[color:navy; padding:8px; border:1px dotted navy;]{ \lim_{n\to\infty} G(n, f) = 1 + \frac{\alpha \Gamma (\frac{1-\alpha}{2})^2}{2 \Gamma(1-\frac{\alpha}{2})^2}. } \label{main_res}\tag{$\diamond$} $$

Our starting point is **@River Li**'s excellent represention,

$$ G(n, f) = 1 + n(n-1) \int_{0}^{\infty} A_0(t)^{n-2}A_1(t)^2 \, \mathrm{d}t, \label{G}\tag{1} $$

where $A_k(t) = \mathbf{E}[X^k e^{-t X^2}]$. Using \eqref{G}, we examine a class of probability distributions and show that the corresponding $G(n, f)$ converges to a finite value as $n \to \infty$.

We first obtain an integral representation of $A_k(t)$. Substituting $y = tx^2$,

\begin{align*}
A_k(t)
= \int_{1}^{\infty} \frac{\alpha}{x^{\alpha+1-k}} e^{-tx^2} \, \mathrm{d}x
= \frac{\alpha}{2} t^{(\alpha-k)/2} \int_{t}^{\infty} \frac{e^{-y}}{y^{(\alpha+2-k)/2}} \, \mathrm{d}y.
\end{align*}

From this, we make several observations about $A_0(t)$ and $A_1(t)$.

> **1.** For $k \in \{0, 1\}$, we have
>
> \begin{align*}
> A_k(t)
> \leq \frac{\alpha}{2} t^{(\alpha-k)/2} \int_{t}^{\infty} \frac{e^{-y}}{t^{(\alpha+2-k)/2}} \, \mathrm{d}y
> = \frac{\alpha}{2t} e^{-t}. \label{bound:Ak}\tag{2}
> \end{align*}

> **2.** When $k = 0$, set $c_0 := \frac{\alpha}{2} \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{1 - e^{-y}}{y^{(\alpha+2)/2}} \, \mathrm{d}y \in (0, \infty)$. Then by using $A_0(0) = 1$, we get
>
> \begin{align*}
> A_0(t)
> &= 1 + A_0(t) - A_0(0) \\
> &= 1 - \frac{\alpha}{2} t^{\alpha/2} \int_{t}^{\infty} \frac{1 - e^{-y}}{y^{(\alpha+2)/2}} \, \mathrm{d}y \\
> &= 1 - c_0 t^{\alpha/2} + \frac{\alpha}{2} t^{\alpha/2} \int_{0}^{t} \frac{1 - e^{-y}}{y^{(\alpha+2)/2}} \, \mathrm{d}y.
> \end{align*}
>
> Since $1 - e^{-y} \leq y$, this gives
>
> $$ 1 - c_0 t^{\alpha/2} \leq A_0(t) \leq 1 - c_0 t^{\alpha/2} + \frac{\alpha}{2 - \alpha} t \label{bound:A0_1}\tag{3} $$
>
> Also, when $t \in (0, 1]$ and with $c_0' := \frac{\alpha}{2} \int_{1}^{\infty} \frac{1 - e^{-y}}{y^{(\alpha+2)/2}} \, \mathrm{d}y \in (0, \infty)$, it follows that
>
> $$ A_0(t) \leq 1 - c_0' t^{\alpha/2} \leq \exp\left( - c_0' t^{\alpha/2} \right). \label{bound:A0_2}\tag{4} $$

> **3.** When $k = 1$, we have $c_1 := \frac{\alpha}{2} \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{e^{-y}}{y^{(\alpha+1)/2}} \, \mathrm{d}y \in (0, \infty)$. Hence,
>
> \begin{align*}
> A_1(t)
> &=  \frac{c_1}{t^{(1-\alpha)/2}} - \frac{\alpha/2}{t^{(1-\alpha)/2}} \int_{0}^{t} \frac{e^{-y}}{y^{(\alpha+1)/2}} \, \mathrm{d}y
> \end{align*}
>
> From this, it follows that
>
> $$  \frac{c_1}{t^{(1-\alpha)/2}} - \frac{\alpha}{1-\alpha} \leq A_1(t) \leq  \frac{c_1}{t^{(1-\alpha)/2}}. \label{bound:A1}\tag{5} $$

Now we return to analyzing the asymptotic behavior of $G(n, f)$ as $n\to\infty$. To make use of \eqref{G}, we introduce two auxiliary quantities:

\begin{align*}
I_n &= n(n-1) \int_{0}^{1} A_0(t)^{n-2}A_1(t)^2 \, \mathrm{d}t, \\
J_n &= n(n-1) \int_{1}^{\infty} A_0(t)^{n-2}A_1(t)^2 \, \mathrm{d}t.
\end{align*}

By invoking \eqref{bound:Ak}, we get

\begin{align*}
J_n
\leq n^2 \int_{1}^{\infty} \left( \frac{\alpha}{2t} e^{-t} \right)^{n} \, \mathrm{d}t
\leq n^2 \left( \frac{\alpha}{2e} \right)^{n}.
\end{align*}

This shows that $J_n \to 0$ exponentially fast. Next, we turn to estimating $I_n$. Plugging \eqref{bound:A1} into $I_n$,

\begin{align*}
I_n
&= n(n-1) \int_{0}^{1} A_0(t)^{n-2} \left( \frac{c_1}{t^{(1-\alpha)/2}} + \mathcal{O}(1) \right)^{2} \, \mathrm{d}t \\
&= c_1^2 n(n-1) \int_{0}^{1} \frac{1}{t^{1-\alpha}} A_0(t)^{n-2} \left( 1 + \mathcal{O}(t^{(1-\alpha)/2}) \right)^{2} \, \mathrm{d}t.
\end{align*}

Substituting $c_0 t^{\alpha/2} = s/n$, or equivalently $t = (s/c_0 n)^{2/\alpha}$,

\begin{align*}
I_n
&= \frac{2 c_1^2 (1 - n^{-1}) }{\alpha c_0^2} \int_{0}^{c_0 n} s A_0\left(\frac{s^{2/\alpha}}{(c_0n)^{2/\alpha}} \right)^{n-2} \left( 1 + \mathcal{O}\Bigl( \frac{s^{(1-\alpha)/\alpha}}{n^{(1-\alpha)/\alpha}} \Bigr) \right)^{2} \, \mathrm{d}s.
\end{align*}

Moreover, as $n \to \infty$,

- the bound \eqref{bound:A0_2} shows that $A_0\left(\frac{s^{2/\alpha}}{(c_0n)^{2/\alpha}} \right)^{n-2}$ is bounded by an exponential function, and
- the estimate \eqref{bound:A0_1} shows that $A_0\left(\frac{s^{2/\alpha}}{(c_0n)^{2/\alpha}} \right)^{n-2} \to e^{-s}$ pointwise.

So by the dominated convergence theorem, we get

$$ I_n
\to \frac{2 c_1^2 }{\alpha c_0^2} \int_{0}^{\infty} se^{-s} \, \mathrm{d}s
= \frac{2 c_1^2 }{\alpha c_0^2}. $$

Moreover, it is not hard to check that $ c_0 = \Gamma(1-\frac{\alpha}{2}) $  and $ c_1 = \frac{\alpha}{2} \Gamma(\frac{1-\alpha}{2}) $. Therefore the desired conclusion \eqref{main_res} follows.

Below Python code computes an approximate value of $G(10^4)$ for $\alpha = \frac{1}{2}$ through Monte Carlo simulation using $10^6$ samples:

```
import numpy as np

def gen_sample(n):
    x = np.random.rand(n) ** (-2)
    return (np.sum(x) ** 2) / np.sum(x ** 2)

data = [gen_sample(10000) for _ in range(1000000)]

# The exact value of lim G(n) is 3.188439615...
np.mean(data)
```

I got $3.1866881493312955$, which is reasonably close to the value $1+\frac{\Gamma (1/4)^2}{4 \Gamma (3/4)^2} = 3.188439615...$ we obtained from \eqref{main_res}.

---

**Footnotes.**

<sup>1) SLLN works whenever the expectation exists in the extended real number line $[-\infty, \infty]$.</sup>

Comment: Nice result for Pareto distribution. What about Pareto for $\alpha = 1$ as in comment?

Comment: @RiverLi, Thank you! When $\alpha = 1$, $G(n)$ diverges to $\infty$ at a speed of $(\log n)^2$ as in my heuristic computation. As for the proof strategy, only the estimate $(4)$ about the asymptotic behavior of $A_1(t)$ as $t \to 0^+$ needs modification. Then with the resulting modification of $(4)$ and mimicking my argument, we should be able to prove my previous comment. I decided not to include $\alpha=1$ case to my answer, though, because OP specifically requested examples for convergent $G(n)$, and more importantly, I'm exhausted now... :s

Comment: For the SLLN to kick in for the sum of squares you need square integrability, $EX^2<\infty$.

Comment: @Math-fun, SLLN holds whenever the expectation *exists* in $[-\infty, \infty]$. In fact, the proof is quite easy assuming SLLN for the case of finite mean, using a truncation argument. See [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1644218/slln-when-the-expectation-in-infinite) for some famous references. :)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the comment. For any iid random sequence $z_i$ you need the first moment to exist for the SLLN to go through for $\bar{z}$. For $X_i^2$ we hence need the second moment of $X_i$ to exist. :-) In your answer, you assume first moment to exist "only", yet use SLLN for $X_i^2$ (this was the point I wishes to clarify).

Comment: @SangchulLee Thanks. :)

Comment: @Math-fun, I guess you missed my point. SLLN actually works even when the expectation is either $+\infty$ or $-\infty$. (Hence, it only doesn't work when the expectation is undefined in $[-\infty,\infty]$.) Indeed, let $(X_i)_{i=1}^{\infty}$ be a sequence of i.i.d. random variables, sampled from the distribution of a r.v. $X$, such that either $\mathbf{E}[|X|]<\infty$, or $\mathbf{E}[X]=+\infty$, or $\mathbf{E}[X]=-\infty$. Then it follows that $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{X_1+\cdots+X_n}{n}=\mathbf{E}[X].$$ This is the version of SLLN I used in my answer and I mentioned in my previous comment.

Answer (score 2):

It does not answer the question, but too long for a comment.

Let $X_i$ follow a Pareto distribution of parameter $\alpha\in(0,1)$. Let $Y = \max\{X_1,\dots,X_n\}$. Using the law of total expectation, we can write that
$$
  G(n) = \mathbb{E}\!\left[\mathbb{E}\!\left[\frac{\left(\sum X_i\right)^2}{\left(\sum {X_i}^2 \right) } \mid Y \right]\right].
$$

For large $n$, we can say that
$$
  \mathbb{E}\!\left[\frac{\left(\sum X_i\right)^2}{\left(\sum {X_i}^2 \right) } \mid Y \right] \sim \frac{((n-1)E[X_1\mid Y] + Y)^2}{(n-1)E[X_1^2\mid Y] +Y^2 }
  = \frac{\left(\frac{\alpha  (n-1) \left(Y-Y^{\alpha }\right)}{(1-\alpha ) \left(Y^{\alpha }-1\right)}+Y\right)^2}{\frac{\alpha  (n-1) \left(Y^2-Y^{\alpha }\right)}{(2-\alpha) \left(Y^{\alpha }-1\right)}+Y^2} .
$$

Then, we can calculate $G(n)$ using that $f_Y(y) = n \,\alpha\, y^{-\alpha -1} \left(1-y^{-\alpha }\right)^{n-1}$, $y>1$. But I couldn't do it analytically, so I plotted in Mathematica as a function of $n$ for $\alpha \in\{1/2,1/3,1/4,1/5\}$.
[[image: G(n) as a function of <span class=]$n$" />](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ORhY0.jpg)

Here is $G(n)$ as a function of $\alpha$ **which is different** from $(1-\alpha)^{-1}$:
[image: G(n) as a function of alpha]

Here is the inverse of the expected value as a function of $\alpha$, which seems to agree with the $1-\alpha$ of [Albrecher & Teugels (2007)](https://www.ams.org/journals/tpms/2007-74-00/S0094-9000-07-00692-8/):
[image: Inverse as a function of alpha]

Comment: This might be a separate question in itself, but when do I know that the tail is heavy enough such that the maximum of $n$ random variables will dominate a sum of $n$ random variables?

Comment: This certainly merits its own question. I imagine the necessary condition is that $E[X]$ does not exist. But I do not know if it is sufficient.

Answer (score 2):

Let us denote
$$\begin{align}
&\bar{X}:=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^nX_i\\
&\bar{X^2}:=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^nX_i^2\\
\end{align}$$
then
$$G(n,f) = n\cdot \mathbb{E}\left(\frac{(\bar{X})^2}{\bar{X^2}}  \right)$$
According to the [multidimensional central limit theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_limit_theorem#Multidimensional_CLT):

$$
\begin{pmatrix}
\bar{X}\\\bar{X^2}  
\end{pmatrix} \xrightarrow[\mathcal{D}]{n \to +\infty}
\begin{pmatrix}
\mathbb{E}(X)\\\mathbb{E}(X^2)
\end{pmatrix} + \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\cdot\mathcal{N}_2\left(  
\begin{pmatrix}
0\\0
\end{pmatrix};
\begin{pmatrix}
Var(X) & Cov(X,X^2)\\
Cov(X,X^2)& Var(X^2)\\
\end{pmatrix}
\right)  \tag{1}
$$
We denote the gaussian vector $(Z,T)$ as follows
$$\begin{pmatrix}
Z\\T
\end{pmatrix} := \mathcal{N}_2\left(  
\begin{pmatrix}
0\\0
\end{pmatrix};
\begin{pmatrix}
Var(X) & Cov(X,X^2)\\
Cov(X,X^2)& Var(X^2)\\
\end{pmatrix}
\right)$$
then from $(1)$

$$
G(n,f) \xrightarrow{n\to +\infty} n\cdot \mathbb{E} \left(\frac{\left(\mathbb{E}(X)+ \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}Z  \right)^2}{\mathbb{E}(X^2) + \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}T}  \right) \tag{2}
$$

If $\mathbb{E}(X) \ne 0$, the numerator of $(2)$ converges to $\mathbb{E}^2(X)$ while the denumerator converges to $\mathbb{E}(X^2)$, the fraction inside the expectation converges to a positive value, then $G(n,f)$ must diverge.

So, we must have
$$\mathbb{E}(X) = 0 \tag{3}$$

Applying $(3)$ to $(2)$, we have
$$ \begin{align}
G(n,f) \xrightarrow{n\to +\infty} n\cdot \mathbb{E} \left(\frac{\left( \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}Z  \right)^2}{\mathbb{E}(X^2) + \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}T}  \right) &=\mathbb{E} \left(\frac{Z^2}{\mathbb{E}(X^2) + \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}T}  \right)  \\
&=\mathbb{E} \left(\frac{Z^2}{\mathbb{E}(X^2)} \cdot \frac{1}{1 + \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} \frac{T}{\mathbb{E}(X^2)}}  \right) \\
&\xrightarrow{n \to +\infty}\mathbb{E} \left(\frac{Z^2}{\mathbb{E}(X^2)}  \right)\tag{4}\\
&=\frac{\mathbb{E}(Z^2)}{\mathbb{E}(X^2)} \\
& = \frac{Var(X)}{\mathbb{E}(X^2)} \\
& =   \frac{\mathbb{E}(X^2) - \mathbb{E}^2(X)}{\mathbb{E}(X^2)} \\
& = 1
\end{align}$$

We conclude that
$$
G(n,f) \xrightarrow{n\to +\infty} 
\begin{cases}
      +\infty  &\text{if} \hspace{1cm} \mathbb{E}(X) \ne 0 \\
      1 &\text{if} \hspace{1cm} \mathbb{E}(X) = 0
    \end{cases}\tag{5}
$$
The result $(5)$ does not depend on the distribution of $X$ but depend on $\mathbb{E}(X)$.

---

**I added the detail for $(4)$**.

By using Taylor expansion, we have

$$\begin{align}
L &:= \mathbb{E} \left(\frac{Z^2}{\mathbb{E}(X^2)} \cdot \frac{1}{1 + \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} \frac{T}{\mathbb{E}(X^2)}}  \right) \\
&=\mathbb{E} \left(\frac{Z^2}{\mathbb{E}(X^2)} \cdot \left(1+\sum_{i=1}^{+\infty} \frac{1}{n^{i/2}}\cdot \frac{T^{i}}{\mathbb{E}^{i}(X^2)}  \right)  \right)\\
&=\mathbb{E} \left(\frac{Z^2}{\mathbb{E}(X^2)} \right) +  \sum_{i=1}^{+\infty} \frac{1}{n^{i/2}}\cdot \mathbb{E} \left(\frac{Z^2 T^{i}}{\mathbb{E}^{i}(X^2)}  \right) \\
\end{align}$$

We observe that the variables $Z^2 T^{2k+1}$ are symetric in distribution and centered at $0$, so, $\mathbb{E}(Z^2 T^{i}) = 0$ for $i$ odd

Then
$$\begin{align}
L &= \mathbb{E} \left(\frac{Z^2}{\mathbb{E}(X^2)} \right) +  \sum_{i=1}^{+\infty} \frac{1}{n^{i}}\cdot \mathbb{E} \left(\frac{Z^2 T^{2i}}{\mathbb{E}^{2i}(X^2)}  \right) \\
&\le \mathbb{E} \left(\frac{Z^2}{\mathbb{E}(X^2)} \right) +  \sum_{i=1}^{+\infty} \frac{1}{n^{i}}\cdot  \frac{\sqrt{\mathbb{E}(Z^4)} \sqrt{ \mathbb{E}( T^{4i})}}{\mathbb{E}^{2i}(X^2)} \\
&\le \mathbb{E} \left(\frac{Z^2}{\mathbb{E}(X^2)} \right) +  \sqrt{\mathbb{E}(Z^4)} \cdot \sum_{i=1}^{+\infty} \frac{1}{n^{i}}\cdot \frac{\sqrt{ \mathbb{E}( T^{4i})}}{\mathbb{E}^{2i}(X^2)} \tag{6}
\end{align}$$

From the [Jensen's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jensen%27s_inequality) for the convex function $f(x):=x^i$ for $i\in \mathbb{N}$, we have:
$$\mathbb{E}(T^{4i}) \le \mathbb{E}^i(T^{4})$$
then
$$\begin{align}
\mathbb{E} \left(\frac{Z^2}{\mathbb{E}(X^2)} \right) < L &\le \mathbb{E} \left(\frac{Z^2}{\mathbb{E}(X^2)} \right) +  \sqrt{\mathbb{E}(Z^4)} \cdot \sum_{i=1}^{+\infty} \left(\frac{1}{n}\cdot  \frac{\mathbb{E}^{1/2}(T^4)}{\mathbb{E}^2(X^2)}  \right)^i  \\
&=\mathbb{E} \left(\frac{Z^2}{\mathbb{E}(X^2)} \right)  + \underbrace{ \frac{1}{n}\cdot  \frac{\mathbb{E}^{1/2}(T^4)}{\mathbb{E}^2(X^2)} \cdot
\frac{1}{1-\frac{1}{n}\cdot  \frac{\mathbb{E}^{1/2}(T^4)}{\mathbb{E}^2(X^2)}}}_\text{converge to $0$ when $n \to +\infty$}
\end{align}$$

Then
$$G(n,f) \xrightarrow{n\to +\infty} \frac{\mathbb{E}(Z^2)}{\mathbb{E}(X^2)}$$

Comment: Hello @NN2, just a quick question: how can we justify that convergence in distribution implies convergence of expectations here? Some uniform integrability argument?

Comment: @Snoop Thank for your remark, I just added the detail for $(4)$ in the end of the answer.

Comment: @NN2 +1 This is nice, but I worry it hits many of the same points as the other answers. Namely, when the CLT applies, or when the SLLN applies, then one gets 
$$G(n,f) \xrightarrow{n\to +\infty} 
\begin{cases}
      +\infty  &\text{if} \hspace{1cm} \mathbb{E}(X) \ne 0 \\
      1 &\text{if} \hspace{1cm} \mathbb{E}(X) = 0
    \end{cases}$$
In particular, these assumptions hold trivially when the support of the random variable is on $[0,1]$.

The more challenging aspect of this question is the case of support on $[0,\infty]$, specifically cases when the moments of $X$ do not exist.

Answer (score 2):

**Some thoughts.**

For some distributions, e.g. uniform distribution, we can obtain the asymptotic expressions in the following way.

Using the identity ($q > 0$)
$$
\frac{1}{q} = \int_0^\infty \mathrm{e}^{-qt}\,\mathrm{d} t,
$$
letting $f_k(t) := \mathbb{E}\left(X_1^k\mathrm{e}^{-t X_1^2}\right)$
for $k = 0, 1, 2, \cdots$, using IBP, we have
\begin{align*}
 &\mathbb{E}\left[\frac{(\sum_i X_i)^2}{\sum_i X_i^2}\right]\\[6pt]
 ={}& 1 + \mathbb{E}\left[\frac{\sum_{1\le i< j \le n} 2X_iX_j}{\sum_i X_i^2}\right]\\[6pt]
 ={}& 1 + \mathbb{E}\left[\left(\sum_{1\le i< j\le n} 2X_iX_j\right) \cdot \int_0^\infty \mathrm{e}^{-t\sum_i X_i^2}\,\mathrm{d} t\right]\\[6pt]
 ={}& 1 + n(n-1)\int_0^\infty \left[\mathbb{E}\left(X_1 \mathrm{e}^{-t X_1^2}\right)\right]^2\left[\mathbb{E}\left(\mathrm{e}^{-t X_1^2}\right)\right]^{n-2}\,\mathrm{d} t\\[6pt]
 ={}& 1 + n(n-1)\int_0^\infty [f_1(t)]^2[f_0(t)]^{n-2}\,\mathrm{d} t\\[6pt]
 ={}& 1 - n\int_0^\infty \frac{[f_1(t)]^2}{f_2(t)}\,\mathrm{d} [f_0(t)]^{n-1} \tag{1}\\[6pt]
 ={}& 1 + n\cdot \lim_{t\to 0^{+}} \frac{[f_1(t)]^2}{f_2(t)}
 + n\int_0^\infty [f_0(t)]^{n-1}\cdot \frac{-2f_1(t)f_3(t)f_2(t) + [f_1(t)]^2f_4(t)}{[f_2(t)]^2}\,\mathrm{d} t
 \tag{2}.
\end{align*}
Explanation:
(1): Use $f_0'(t) = f_2(t)$.
(2): Use $\lim_{t\to 0^{+}} f_0(t) = 1$,
and $\lim_{t\to \infty} \frac{[f_1(t)]^2}{f_2(t)}[f_0(t)]^{n-1} = 0$
using $f_0(t)f_2(t) \ge [f_1(t)]^2$ for all $t \ge 0$ (C-S inequality) and $\lim_{t\to \infty} f_0(t) = 0$.

$\phantom{2}$

- Ex. 1: Uniform distribution $X_1 \sim U(0, 1)$

Using IBP for (2), we have
\begin{align*}
 &\mathbb{E}\left[\frac{(\sum_i X_i)^2}{\sum_i X_i^2}\right]\\[6pt]
 ={}& 1 + n\cdot \lim_{t\to 0^{+}} \frac{[f_1(t)]^2}{f_2(t)} - \int_0^\infty \frac{-2f_1(t)f_3(t)f_2(t) + [f_1(t)]^2f_4(t)}{[f_2(t)]^3}\,\mathrm{d} [f_0(t)]^n\\[6pt]
 ={}& 1 + n\cdot \lim_{t\to 0^{+}} \frac{[f_1(t)]^2}{f_2(t)}
 + \lim_{t\to 0^{+}} \frac{-2f_1(t)f_3(t)f_2(t) + [f_1(t)]^2f_4(t)}{[f_2(t)]^3} \\[6pt]
 &\qquad + \int_0^\infty [f_0(t)]^n \cdot \left(\frac{-2f_1(t)f_3(t)f_2(t) + [f_1(t)]^2f_4(t)}{[f_2(t)]^3}\right)'\,\mathrm{d} t
\end{align*}
which gives
$$G(n; U(0, 1)) = \frac34 n + \frac{1}{10} + o(1).$$
Explanation:

(i): $\lim_{t\to 0^{+}} \frac{[f_1(t)]^2}{f_2(t)} = \frac{\left[\mathbb{E}\left(X_1 \right)\right]^2}{\mathbb{E}\left(X_1^2\right)} = \frac34$.

(ii):  $\lim_{t\to 0^{+}} \frac{-2f_1(t)f_3(t)f_2(t) + [f_1(t)]^2f_4(t)}{[f_2(t)]^3}
= \frac{-2\mathbb{E}\left(X_1\right)\mathbb{E}\left(X_1^3\right)\mathbb{E}\left(X_1^2\right) + [\mathbb{E}\left(X_1\right)]^2\mathbb{E}\left(X_1^4\right)}{[\mathbb{E}\left(X_1^2\right)]^3} = - \frac{9}{10}$.

(iii): $|(\frac{-2f_1(t)f_3(t)f_2(t) + [f_1(t)]^2f_4(t)}{[f_2(t)]^3})'|$ is bounded by constant $C$. We have
$|\int_0^\infty [f_0(t)]^n \cdot (\frac{-2f_1(t)f_3(t)f_2(t) + [f_1(t)]^2f_4(t)}{[f_2(t)]^3})'\,\mathrm{d} t|
\le C \int_0^\infty [f_0(t)]^n\, \mathrm{d} t = o(1)$.

$\phantom{2}$

- Ex. 2: Pareto distribution $X_1 = \frac{1}{x^2}{\bf 1}_{x > 1}$

We have $\lim_{t\to 0^{+}} \frac{[f_1(t)]^2}{f_2(t)} = 0$. We have
\begin{align*}
 &\mathbb{E}\left[\frac{(\sum_i X_i)^2}{\sum_i X_i^2}\right]\\[6pt]
 ={}& 1
 + n\int_0^\infty [f_0(t)]^{n-1}\cdot \frac{-2f_1(t)f_3(t)f_2(t) + [f_1(t)]^2f_4(t)}{[f_2(t)]^2}\,\mathrm{d} t.
\end{align*}
(*Note*: $\mathbb{E}(X_1) = \infty$ and $\mathbb{E}(X_1^2) = \infty$.)

To be continued.

Comment: Nice observation! Following this idea and assuming $f_{X_i}(x) = \frac{1}{x^2}\mathbf{1}_{\{x>1\}}$ is the Pareto distribution, then my back-of-the-envelope computation gives $$G(n) \approx 1 + \int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-\sqrt{\pi x}}\left(\log n - \frac{\log s + \gamma}{2}\right)^2 \, \mathrm{d}s. $$

Comment: @SangchulLee Thanks. Your expression is nice. Did you deal with something like my last expression (Ex. 2) in the new version?

Comment: I started from the representation $$G(n)=1 + n(n-1)\int_{0}^{\infty} f_0(t)^{n-2} f_1(t)^2 \,\mathrm{d}t$$ and then utilized various asymptotic formulas for $f_0$ and $f_1$. Take my claim with a grain of salt, though, because my computation is only heuristic. (Of course, I believe it can be improved to a rigorous proof, and Monte-Carlo simulation up to $n=102400$ shows that the above formula works well.)

Comment: @SangchulLee Very nice.